# Sockets server cleint

Tags: java, sockets, jsf

I have web Application JSF which is acting as a client and another java application acting as the server. Now I have a startEngine() function which starts the application on the server and that works fine. I also have another function called addWebSite which is suppose to add a website to the same application that was opened before. My first call to the server works but the second doesnt and there are more functions I would like to call on the server.

This is my startEngine Function and addWebSite Function. NB: This is a managedbean Sessioned but this shouldnt affect anything

```
public void startEgineNow() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();


    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        // get student from database
        IPAddress myAddress = session.get(IPAddress.class, sendToSocketId);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        if (myAddress.getIpAddress() != null) {
            clientSocket = new Socket(myAddress.getIpAddress(), myAddress.getPortNumber());


            PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                BufferedReader in =
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                out.println("startEngine");
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }

    }       
}

public void addWebsite() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

    System.out.println(sendToSocketId);
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            // get student from database
            IPAddress myAddress = session.get(IPAddress.class, sendToSocketId);

             Sites sites = new Sites(addSite);
             sites.setAddress(myAddress);

             session.persist(sites);


             session.getTransaction().commit();


             if (myAddress.getIpAddress() != null) {
                    clientSocket = new Socket(myAddress.getIpAddress(), myAddress.getPortNumber());


                    PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                        BufferedReader in =
                            new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                        out.println("addWebSite");
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                }


            } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }

            }       
}
```

This is my server side code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NumberFormatException, IOException {

    MainListener myListener = new MainListener();

    ServerSocket serverSocket =
            new ServerSocket(5000);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputLine.equals("startEngine")) {
                myListener.runDesktop();

            }else if(inputLine.equals("addWebSite")){
                myListener.addWebsite("https://www.buzzfeed.com/");
            }
        }
```

When I start the engine with the startEngine method I want the server to remain open for other calls as well. and only close when I send in the close() function from the client, Please what am I doing wrong here

Comment: You need to accept multiple clients, in a loop, but I can't see the point of this client/server architecture, especially as you don't know how to implement it. You should integrate the server code into the webapp and call it directly via method invocation.

Comment: Well as you can see I am implementing the client/server architecture but it only fires the first time. so my question is how to structure the architecture to receive other requests as well.

Comment: Well as you can see I've already answered that, and all I can see is that you are embarking on an architecture that isn't optimal and that you don't know how to implement.